# How to view progress in ESXi of RAID recovery

Tags: raid, vmware-esxi

We have a RAID configuration. After a failure when a new hard drive is being written to, is there a way to use ESXi to view the progress so we know how much longer until completion?

Comment: What server manufacturer/model? What type of RAID controller?

Comment: @ewwhite LSA MegaRIAD SAS 9271-4i

Answer (score 2):

No; when a RAID rebuild is being handled by the hardware RAID controller, it's unlikely that the information is exposed to the OS in any way (though maybe you can get some info on the hardware status tab, depending on your hardware).

The way you'll want to get at this info is to check your hardware management tools - iLO/DRAC/etc.

Comment: I can speak to HP Proliant servers, if you load the HP Tool Bundle and/or use the HP build of ESXi, you can enable and connect to the shell and use the HPACUCLI to pull information from the array controller from the command line including the status of a RAID rebuild.

Comment: Actually, today and on modern servers, that will be the `hpssacli` tool.